# How is code replaced for atomic operations when <stdatomic.h> is included in a file

Tags: c, gcc

During a school project for concurrent programming, we included `<stdatomic.h>` in a project and modified the appropriate data types of variable declarations to allow atomic operations on some global variables.

When I began to look into the stdatomic header, I saw that a bunch of data types and operations were defined to allow the desired behavior.

What I noticed when I compiled and did an object dump was that memory fences were now added. I also make the assumption that for operations like `my_atomic_variable += 5;` are replaced with some of the macros/functions declared in the stdatomic header.

What I would like to know is how simply by changing the data types in the source code, memory fences and such are added. I imagine at some point functions like `__atomic_signal_fence` are subbed into the source code where read/writes take place, but I have no idea how this is actually done. Unfortunately reading the header files hasn't helped a lot. I get the impression there is some concept of how compilers work that I am not familiar with or don't understand.

**UPDATE**

In response to the comments, let me clarify a little bit. The way I understand C is that there are certain basic data types, like an `int`. I imagine stdatomic implements `atomic_int` in terms of `int` and some extra code. It seems to me that when some atomic int is assigned like `my_atomic_int = 1`, somehow this is changed into a more complex set of instructions than would normally be required to assign a regular integer.

What I don't understand is what could be present inside the stdatomic code that would allow the use of the `=` operator since C does not support operator overloading. What code actually does this? Does gcc know how to translate the atomic instructions because it has atomic data types built into it? If not, how could I write code similar to that of stdatomic where gcc would know how to handle the `=` operator for my custom data type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly is std::atomic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978324/what-exactly-is-stdatomic)

Comment: It's the compiler's job to translate your C program into machine instructions that effect the behaviour described by your program.

Comment: That's the same question as "Why does trhe compiler generate different code when I change `int` types to `_Complex` types.

Comment: I have updated the problem to try and more accurately describe what I am trying to find out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268562/what-are-intrinsics