# What is the C++20 "addressing restriction" good for?

Tags: c++, c++20, std

According to cppreference.com, C++20 introduces the ["addressing restriction"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std#Addressing_restriction) for standard library functions:

> ##### Addressing restriction
>
> The behavior of a C++ program is unspecified (possibly ill-formed) if it explicitly or implicitly attempts to form a pointer, reference (for free functions and static member functions) or pointer-to-member (for non-static member functions) to a standard library function or an instantiation of a standard library function template, unless it is designated an addressable function (see below).
>
> Following code was well-defined in C++17, but leads to unspecified behaviors and possibly fails to compile since C++20:
>
> ```
> #include <cmath>
> #include <memory>
>  
> int main()
> {
>     auto fptr0 = &std::betaf; // by unary operator&
>     auto fptr1 = std::addressof(std::betal); // by std::addressof
>     auto fptr2 = std::riemann_zetaf; // by function-to-pointer implicit conversion
>     auto &fref = std::riemann_zetal; // forming a reference
> }
> ```

Why was this introduced?

Especially with regard to backwards compatibility of the language, this seems to be a change that breaks a lot of existing code. What benefit does this provide that makes worth such a breaking change?

Comment: the "Following code was well-defined in C++17" part is odd. I am almost certain that it was never allowed (only for functions where it is explicitly allowed)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268562/what-are-intrinsics

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55687044/179910

Comment: There might be overloads other than the ones in the language spec. So you cannot know for sure what the exact function signature is. http://eel.is/c++draft/member.functions

Comment: @BoP I guess it also allows some standard library functions to be implemented as macros...?

Answer (score 7):

It was never "well-defined", it just happened to work on your/some/most implementation. (CppReference is wrong here)

Buried in the introduction of the library section of the standard is a description of what implementors must provide. For (say) `std:: riemann_zetal`, what's required is that there's a "thing" that can be called using function-call syntax, that takes a single `float` parameter, and returns something that can be converted to a `float`.

So, this is a perfectly legal implementation:

```
template <typename FP>
FP ZETA(FP f, int flags = 0) { /* code here */ } 

#define riemann_zetaf(x)  ZETA<float>(x, 23)
```

But, you can't take the address of `riemann_zetaf` because there is no such beast.

Note that even without the macro, you have no guarantee that `addressof(riemann_zetal)` would return a function that takes exactly one parameter.  The only guarantee you have is that you can call it with one parameter.

If you need something that you can take the address of, define it yourself:

```
float riemann_zetal (float x) { return std::riemann_zetal(x); }
```

and then take the address of *that* instead.

Comment: I doubt the implementation allowed to define such a macro, as it could conflict with user code.

Comment: You mean like `toupper`, say?

Comment: @MarshallClow It would conflict in that a user should be able to declare their own `riemann_zetal` in their scope (it is not a reserved identifier), which doesn't work if it is a macro. (Specifically your suggestion at the end would also fail to compile if the standard library uses the macro implementation.)

Comment: @MarshallClow `C17 7.1.4 Use of library functions /1` permits C standard library functions to be macros. I can't find the same wording in C++ standard for C++ standard library entities.

Comment: I think the macro argument is taking the discussion away from the main point, which is: the standard library can have default parameters, templates, or add additional overloads, etc, such that the address is ambiguous, not a matching function, or not available in the first place.  There are no guarantees about this ever working, and relying on it is only "probably ok" in reality but not according to the spec.  Adhering to the specification protects you against future library changes.

Comment: Also, I try to always avoid getting in arguments about the standard library with Marshall Clow.  :)

Comment: meanwhile updating cppreference to hopefully be less wrong

Comment: @MarshallClow Can you prove that by citing the C++17 standard? I don't want to accept the answer without being sure it is correct. Currently I am not sure. Looks like [P0551](https://wg21.link/p0551) introduced the change to C++20.

Comment: Ok, I was over-broad in my characterization.   Implementations are allowed to add extra template arguments to classes, and (I think, but am not sure ATM) to functions (member and non-member), but can only add additional default arguments to member functions.

Note that non-member functions can be declared as `inline`, which would make taking their address difficult.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion